# How to work this sample survey problem out?

Tags: hypothesis-testing, sample, computational-statistics, survey-sampling

> Suppose in a country there are $N$ states. You select by simple random sampling without replacement (SRSWOR) $n$ states where $n<N$. Now assume for each $i=1,2,...,N$, state $i$ has in total $K_i$ cities. In your sample of $n$ states, you again select, for each state $j$, $j=1,2,...,n$, by SRSWOR, $k_j$ cities. For each city you select, you know its population, denoted by $P_{ij}$ if it is the population of $j$-th city in $i$-th sample, $i=1,2,...,n$, and $j=1,2,...,k_i$. Give an estimator of the following along with their standard errors:
>
> a) total population in the country
>
> b) mean population per city in the entire country

So here is how I approached:

> Let $\overline{y}$ denote the mean population of my **entire** sample i.e. $\overline{y}=\dfrac{1}{k_1+k_2+...+k_n}\sum_{i=1}^n\sum_{j=1}^{k_i}p_{ij}$. Then in SRSWOR, we know that sample mean is an u.e. of population mean, hence if the mean population in the country is $\overline{Y}$ then an estimator of $\overline{Y}$ is $\overline{y}$. So estimator of the total population is $(K_1+K_2+...+K_N) \overline{Y}$ whose estimator is $(K_1+K_2+...+K_N) \overline{y}$.
>
> Using the variance. of $\overline{y}$ in SRSWOR an estimate of the variance. of $\overline{y}$ is $(\dfrac{1}{k_1+k_2+...+k_n}-\dfrac{1}{K_1+K_2+...K_N})\dfrac{1}{k_1+k_2+...+k_n-1}\sum_{i,j} (pij-\overline{y})^2$
>
> So using the formula $Var((K_1+...+K_N)\overline{y})=(K_1+...+K_N^2)Var(\overline{y})$ we get the variance, and by taking square root we will get s.e. of our estimator.
>
> b) I do not understand what this question means. What does mean sheep population per city mean? Shouldn't its estimator be just $\overline{y}$?

Comment: For (b), how do you know how many cities the country has?

Comment: Actually I talked to my professor. This question is based on two-stage cluster sampling which has not yet been taught to me. So maybe I should close the question?